# Loading a select with jQuery: missing elements

Tags: jquery, xml, html-select

This issue is incredibly weird. I'm triying to load a select with a list of towns. I have a function that collects the towns from a .xml file and returns an array with them, and another function that calls the former, and loads the select with the retrieved towns. The function that parses the xml works fine. But the function loading the select doesn't; it only load the first element in the select (there are ten towns in the xml, that are succesfully retrieved by the function that parses the xml file). What is more, if I just debug it with firebug adding several breakpoints, or if I add an alert in the function to show the town array length, then it "magically" works. It's absurd and totally annoying.

Here you have my code:

```
function PrecargarCampos(){
/*this function loads the select */

    var pueblos = getMunicipios(); //retrieves towns from an .xml
    $(".municipio").each(function() {
        for (i=0;i<pueblos.length;i++) {
            var option = "<option value='" + pueblos[i] + "'>" + pueblos[i] + "</option>";
            $(this).append(option);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, if I add an alert...

```
function PrecargarCampos(){
/* this function loads the select */

    var pueblos = getMunicipios(); //retrieves towns from an .xml
    **alert("Number of towns" + pueblos.length);**
    $(".municipio").each(function() {
        for (i=0;i<pueblos.length;i++) {
            var option = "<option value='" + pueblos[i] + "'>" + pueblos[i] + "</option>";
            $(this).append(option);
        }
    });
}
```

... it incredibly works.

I'll also add the piece of code of the function retrieving the towns from the .xml. After debugging it individually, it seems to works fine:

```
function getMunicipios () {
/* retrieves town list from .xml */

    var municipios = [];
    municipios.push("Foo town");
    var url = getURLroot() + "/data/lists/municip.xml"; //get .xml path

    $.get(url, function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("municip").each(function () {
            var nom = $(this).find('nom').text();
            var prov = $(this).find('prov').text();
            var muni = nom + " (" + prov + ")";
            municipios.push(muni);
        });
    });

    return municipios; 
}
```

var municipios is an array that should have 10 items, but in the end, the select is only loaded with the "Foo town" value. As I said, if I turn on the debugger or add a simple alert, the select is correctly loaded with 10 towns.

I'm totally confused and not knowing how to solve it. I will thank any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You select have a id?

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 $("#id_of_select").append("<option value='"+pueblos[i].nombre+"'>"Pueblo"</option>");  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your code is not run as you expect, in a "linear" way.
That is because you are using "onSuccess" function in the jQuery.get() in getMunicipios(). It will do:

```
var municipios = [];
municipios.push("Foo town");
var url = getURLroot() + "/data/lists/municip.xml"; //get .xml path
```

and then it will directly go to:

```
return municipios;
```

and only then, it will do:

```
$.get(url, function (xml) {
    $(xml).find("municip").each(function () {
        var nom = $(this).find('nom').text();
        var prov = $(this).find('prov').text();
        var muni = nom + " (" + prov + ")";
        municipios.push(muni);
    });
});
```

Thus if you use the variable **pueblos** too early, your list won't have time to be filled. At this point you will only get the first element that you added. 
To check whether I am correct or not, you can put an alert in the `$.get(url, function (xml) {`, and one just before the `return municipios;`, then you will have the order in which your code is run.


I may be wrong about that, though.


You can try:

```
function PrecargarCampos(){
/*this function loads the select */

    getMunicipios(function(pueblos) {
        $(".municipio").each(function() {
            for (i=0;i<pueblos.length;i++) {
                var option = "<option value='" + pueblos[i] + "'>" + pueblos[i] + "</option>";
                $(this).append(option);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```
function getMunicipios (callback) {
/* retrieves town list from .xml */

    var municipios = [];
    municipios.push("Foo town");
    var url = getURLroot() + "/data/lists/municip.xml"; //get .xml path

    $.get(url, function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("municip").each(function () {
            var nom = $(this).find('nom').text();
            var prov = $(this).find('prov').text();
            var muni = nom + " (" + prov + ")";
            municipios.push(muni);
        });
        callback(municipios);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You are right, Rick. Simply adding a setTimeout delaying (just 1 second) the execution of the main block allows getMunicipios to collect all the data from the xml and pushing data into array BEFORE trying to load the select. Anyway, the callback solution you suggested is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Following Rick's suggestions, I ended up with this:

```
function PrecargarCampos(){

var pueblos = getMunicipios();
setTimeout(function(){
     $(".municipio").each(function() {
        for (i=0;i<pueblos.length;i++) {
           var option = "<option value='" + pueblos[i] + "'>" + pueblos[i] + "</option>";
           $(this).append(option);
        }
        $(this).append("<option value='Foo town'>Foo town</option>");
     });
  }, 1000); 
}
```

This worked for me. The setTimeout allows the function getMunicpios to perform a complete iteration BEFORE using the returned array (pueblos) to load the select.